# How can I access an external module in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a file containing a module as in below

> ROOT/database/models.ts

```
module Model {
  export interface Inbox {
    title: string;
    msg: string;
  }
  export interface User{
    Id: string;
    Name: string;
  }
}
```

I want to access the interfaces from the main file. See what i tried

> ROOT/pages/main.ts

```
import { Model} from '../database/models'; //<-- here is my problem

export class WorkerPostbidPage {

   myinbox:Model.Inbox; // <-- And I want to call it as this

   TestMethod() {
    this.myinbox = {
        title:"new msg", 
        msg:"you have an alert"
     }
   }
}
```

But when I copy the external model file content into the main.ts like below it works fine

```
module Model {
  export interface Inbox {
    title: string;
    msg: string;
  }
  export interface User{
    Id: string;
    Name: string;
  }
}

export class WorkerPostbidPage {

   myinbox:Model.Inbox; // <-- And I want to call it as this

   TestMethod() {
    this.myinbox = {
        title:"new msg", 
        msg:"you have an alert"
     }
   }
}
```

I guess I might be doing something wrong, or am I missing some parts

Comment: i have tried that, and besides that will never locate the file correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite the model.ts file so it conforms to the ES6 module.

```js
  export interface Inbox {
    title: string;
    msg: string;
  }
  export interface User{
    Id: string;
    Name: string;
  }
```

Then you should be able to import them like this.

```
import { Inbox } from '../database/models';
```

Comment: why can't i access them through the Model namespace. Does it go against  some standards. I really would have preferred it with the namespace.

Comment: but, looking at my second approach of copying the content into the same file. It worked perfectly.

Comment: yeah the way you have it written the module itself was not exported. And thus couldn't be imported.

Comment: the es6 module standard defines what you need to do.

Comment: also the module keyword is mainly used for 'handmade' modules, when you don't use a module loader.

Comment: thank you so much. I think this the best approach for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cant import an external module using this approach.
The external module will ultimately be added to the global scope, so you should treat it as such.

Assuming you are using amd modules, something like this should work

```
declare module Model{
    interface Inbox{
        title: string,
        msg: string
    }
}

/// <amd-dependency path="../database/models"/>

export class WorkerPostbidPage {

    myinbox:Model.Inbox; // <-- And I want to call it as this

    TestMethod() {
        this.myinbox = {
            title:"new msg", 
            msg:"you have an alert"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is amd ..?